# Web Api Service self hosted in Windows Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, portforwarding

Web Api Service self hosted in Windows Service doesn't work with port forwarding, keeps saying connection actively refused. If you use the machine url directly works fine. If you use router url/port, which is port forwarded to web api service machine where selfhosting is taking place. The connection problem appears. To me this looks like the web api service can't recognize the port forwarding.